# How to Simplify this code. Creates Rows from Array

Tags: javascript

How would I simplify this code? WHat Im trying to accomplish is to make my array of numbers into rows based on my variables. In this cased its 5 x 4. Want it to look like this

0 0 0 0 0

0 0 0 0 0

0 0 0 0 0

0 0 0 0 0

Now I have it and had help here on Stack, but an not 100% sure this is the easier way to do this. Remove the commas and separate into rows and columns

Code

```
//Grid Row
const gridRow = 4;
//Grid Column
const gridCol = 5;
// Show Grid
const grid = ["0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0"];
/** Pretty-print the grid via function **/
function printGrid() {
  let res = "";
  for (let r = 0; r < gridRow; r++) {
    let srow = "";
    for (let c = 0; c < gridCol; c++) {
      srow += " " + grid[r * gridCol + c];
    }
    res += srow.substr(1) + '\n';
  }
  return res;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! If the code works and you're looking for advice on improving it, [codereview.se] is the appropriate place. But see https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5777/a-guide-to-code-review-for-stack-overflow-users first.

Comment: Why are you using a 1-dimensional array for a grid in the first place? Why isn't it an array of arrays?

Comment: how would you go about this?

Comment: ```const grid = [["0", "0", "0", "0", "0"], ["0", "0", "0", "0", "0"], ["0", "0", "0", "0", "0"], ["0", "0", "0", "0", "0"]];```

Comment: how would I go about separating that into the format I need? Thanks for the help

Comment: In the loop, you use `grid[r][c]` instead of `grid[r * gridCol + c]`

Comment: An example? Tried this and it works but then breaks shortly after with undefined.

Comment: Then you have some other problem.

Comment: All the code in your application will have to be rewritten to use this grid layout, not just the printing code.

Comment: thats fine was just wondering if there was a simpler way of doing it even if I have to re write some code

Comment: Simpler way of doing what? printing the grid that's in a 1-dimensional array, or designing your whole application?

Comment: printing the grid, was just trying to simplify that part of the code.

Comment: You can replace the inner loop with `srow = grid.slice(r*gridCol, r*(gridCol + 1)).join(" ")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of concatenating strings and then slicing to remove the extra spaces, use `.join()` to concatenate arrays with a delimiter.

You can use `slice()` to extract parts of an array.

```js
//Grid Row
const gridRow = 4;
//Grid Column
const gridCol = 5;
// Show Grid
const grid = ["0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0"];
/** Pretty-print the grid via function **/
function printGrid() {
  const resArray = [];
  for (let r = 0; r < gridRow; r++) {
    const srow = grid.slice(gridCol * r, gridCol * (r + 1)).join(" ");
    resArray.push(srow);
  }
  return resArray.join("\n");
}

console.log(printGrid())
```

Answer (score 1):

You can compute the "glue" for each index. If `index % gridCol === 0` then it's the start of a row, otherwise it's a column

```js
//Grid Row
const gridRow = 4;
//Grid Column
const gridCol = 5;
// Show Grid

const grid = ["0", "0", "0", "1", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0"]

const result = grid.reduce((left, right, i) => left + (i % gridCol ? " " : "\n") + right);
console.log(result);
```

This code assumes that `grid` is of the correct length and of dimensions >= 1x1.

Answer (score 0):

```
console.log([...Array(gridRow).keys()].map(i => grid.slice(gridCol*i, gridCol*(i+1)).join(' ')).join('\n'));
```

Answer (score -1):

```
const grid = Array(4).fill(Array(5).fill(0))

(4) [Array(5), Array(5), Array(5), Array(5)]
0: (5) [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
1: (5) [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
2: (5) [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
3: (5) [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

Each row refers to a different Array

[image: Each row refers to a different Array]

Comment: This is wrong. All the rows are references to the same array.

Comment: `grid[0] == grid[1]` returns `true`

Comment: `row0[0] = 1` then `console.log(row1)` and you'll see it.

Comment: This also doesn't answer the question. He already has the `grid` variable, the question is how to print it in rows.

Comment: const a = 1
const b = 1

a == b // true

It has the same value, but are not reference to the same element

Comment: But objects and arrays are different. They're only `==` if they're the same object, not if they have the same contents.

Comment: Try my second test and you'll see.

Comment: You are right!!

Comment: simplest would be `Array(4).fill().map(() => Array(5).fill(0))`